# Construct a deterministic finite state automaton

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, automata

Construct a deterministic finite-state automaton that recognizes the set of all bit strings that end with 10.

[image]

This is what I drew. Not sure if its correct. State 2 is the final state. Am I missing anything?

EDIT: Think this is it.

[image: A few changes.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DFA recognizes the strings that *contain* $10$ somewhere as a substring. You want to recognize only those that *end in* $10$ (though they may of course have other $10$ substrings internally). You need to change the transitions out of $s_2$. If you’re in $s_2$ and get any more input, you’re essentially starting over as if you were in $s_0$ getting the very first input. Thus, an input of $0$ should just take you back to $s_0$. Where should an input of $1$ take you?

Comment: Just edited it and included the new one! Is that right?

Comment: @Ricardo: Yes, that’s right, except that you need to make $s_2$ a final state, just as it was before.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help again.

Comment: @Ricardo: My pleasure!